# Understanding where python instances live in osx

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Why is the default installation of python seem to live in `/usr/bin/python` and additional installations in other paths (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python3`)?

Does the `local` directory contain installations local to the terminal instance?

(I screwed up a lot of my python because I wasn't using pyenv, so I am starting over and trying to understand how these things work from the ground up so I don't get lost again.)

Comment: Possibly helpful or related [Difference between /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin \[duplicate\]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259231/difference-between-usr-bin-and-usr-local-bin)

Comment: So this is a duplicate of a duplicate lol.

Comment: Post-ception...but on a more serious note, what is then the best order for my PATH?

Comment: Never touch the system install versions (I once did and eventually ended up reinstalling my OS). Use a package manager such as conda. https://conda.io/docs/